# How to make a shooting range for guns in unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my wepons to have a shooting range in my 2D game.For example if the bullet is out of range then destroy the bullet.Is it a problem if i don't use RayCast?
My script for the Wepon:

```
//Initialization
public GameObject Bullet;
public Transform FirePoint;
//WeponStats
public float BulletSpeed;
public int Damage;
public float Range;
private float TimeBtwShots;
public float StartTimeBtwShots;

private void Start()
{

}
private void Update()
{

    if (TimeBtwShots <= 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
            TimeBtwShots = StartTimeBtwShots;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        TimeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
void Shoot()
{
    GameObject bullet2 = Instantiate(Bullet, FirePoint.position, FirePoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody2D rb = bullet2.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.AddForce(FirePoint.right * BulletSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse); 
}
```

And for the bullet:

```
public float Delay;

void Start()
{
    Destroy(gameObject, Delay);
}
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
   if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    { //take damage function, nothing important
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Wepon_Script script_W = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Wepon").GetComponent<Wepon_Script>(); //Wepon script
        Enemy_Core script_E = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<Enemy_Core>(); //Enemy script
        script_E.TakeDamage(script_W.Damage);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93RgP.png)

Comment: Are you not satisfied with your current approach of destroying the bullet after a certain time delay?  If so, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're already destroying the bullet after a delay:

```
Destroy(gameObject, Delay);
```

If you want the bullet to be destroyed after a distance traveled you could divide the distance by the speed.

```
Destroy(gameObject, Range / BulletSpeed);
```

If you want to measure dynamic distance traveled you could keep a track of it inside the bullet.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    var distanceDelta = (transform.position - lastPos).magnitude;
    distanceTravelled += distanceDelta;
    lastPos = transform.position;

    if (distanceTravelled > Range) Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: ty for helping me